# MPLABX MPASM assembler Alternative with code folding option

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip, mplab, code-folding

I just started using MPLABX from MPLAB 8.92.  I like the new setup but the code folding option is not available for MPASM. Is there an alternative assembler that that will offer code folding ? Is ther another way to hide selected code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use code folding in MPASM you had to use tags like this:

```
;<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="this asm is folded">
    movlw   1
    movlw   2
    movlw   3
 ;</editor-fold>
```

Where the `defaultstate` and `desc` settings are optional.

[see here](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1001558.aspx)